# debugging ruby 1.9.3 script using eclipse JUNO

Tags: ruby, eclipse, debugging

i am trying to debug a simple ruby script using eclipse JUNO release and DLTK version 4.0.0.201206120848

i installed ruby-1.9.3-p194 with the following gems

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
bundler (1.2.0)
columnize (0.3.6)
debugger (1.2.0)
debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.3)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.9)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta14)
ruby-debug-ide19 (0.4.12)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.7)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
```

but Eclipse debugger throws the following error:

ECLIPSE CONSOLE OUTPUT

```
/tmp/dltk6585.tmp/debugger/AbstractRunner.rb:97: warning: else without rescue is useless
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /tmp/dltk6585.tmp/debugger/AbstractRunner.rb:94: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
                when nil: NullLogManager.new 
                         ^
/tmp/dltk6585.tmp/debugger/AbstractRunner.rb:95: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
                when 'stdout': StdoutLogManager.new 
                    ^
/tmp/dltk6585.tmp/debugger/AbstractRunner.rb:95: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
                when 'stdout': StdoutLogManager.new 
                              ^
/tmp/dltk6585.tmp/debugger/AbstractRunner.rb:105: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /tmp/dltk6585.tmp/debugger/FastRunner.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

The weirdest thing is that the same thing using ruby version 1.8.7 works fine.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the DLTK team did not have maintainers to update the framework for ruby 1.9.

I think this has been fixed but as of now I don't think it is yet in a build. See Eclipse bug 345976:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345976

Answer (score 0):

Confirming Chad's response, this does seem to have been fixed in DLTK version 5.  After uninstalling version 4 and installing version 5 from here http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/5.0/ (don't forget to uncheck "Group items by category" in the Eclipse "Install" dialog in order to see the uncategorized items) I am no longer receiving the error.

I'm running Kepler Eclipse version 4.3.1 on Arch Linux.